# Insultos blandos pero coloridos

Tags: coloquialismos, insultos, lenguage-despectivo

Tengo una gran colección de novelas juveniles ilustradas en formato de comic (Dickens, Dumas, Salgari, Twain, Verne, etc.) Tienen unos 40 años y el texto está escrito en Barcelona (creia que eran traducciones, pero ya no estoy seguro pues en la esquina de una viñeta el dibujante escribió "Casa Mitjana").

Algo que es muy entretenido es leer los peculiares insultos que se dirigen los personajes en escenas de acción. He aquí una muestra (**actualizada**):

`atorrante` `bellaco` `berzotas` `botarate` `canalla` `desdichado` `gandul` `granuja` `infeliz` `majadero` `malandrín` `mentecato` `mequetrefe` `merluzo` `pelmazo` `petimetre` `rufián` `sabandija` `tontaina` `truhán` `villano` `zoquete`

Algunas de estas palabras son comunes, pero la mayoria no las he visto en otros lados, a excepción quizá de Mortadelo y Filemón. Mi impresión es que los vocablos coloridos intentan sustituir a palabras más fuertes que no habrían sido permitidas en aquellos tiempos.

> - ¿Tengo razón? ¿O eran realmente expresiones comunes?
> - ¿Se usan en otros países?
> - ¿Qué otros insultos similares faltan en mi lista?

Comment: He leído en alguna entrevista a un dibujante de Bruguera (la principal editorial de historietas de España en esa época) que, en efecto, usaban esas palabras porque la censura no les habría permitido otras. Así que intentaban, al menos, hacerlas humorísticas y, como dices, coloridas.

Comment: @Gorpik: Una referencia seria el candidato ideal para ser la respuesta seleccionada...

Comment: Por eso lo he escrito como comentario, porque no tengo la referencia, desgraciadamente.

Comment: @Gorpik Creo que esta página del blog dedicado a los [cómics Bruguera](http://seronoser.free.fr/bruguera/elhumordelaescuelabruguera.htm#h2) sirve, apartado *Hallazgos del lenguaje* para más ejemplos y una lectura para ver donde llegaban los tentáculos de la censura y las triquiñuelas de la editorial para evitarlos.

Comment: @AlexBcn En efecto, buen hallazgo. No menciona la censura, pero tal vez el autor haya considerado que es superfluo dada la época de que trata. Por cierto, a quien sí menciona de pasada es a Casamitjana, el dibujante de la historieta que menciona Rodrigo en su pregunta.

Comment: Y la seccion "Hallazgs del Lenguaje"...
@AlexBcn: Me parece que tu comentario, transformado a respuesta, calificaria para aceptarse.

Comment: Que buen tema, @RodrigoA.Pérez! A mi me gustaban mucho "lechuguino" y "gusarapo".

Comment: Para no empujar repetidamente la pregunta a primer lugar, guardo aqui ejemplos que quiero agregar mas tarde: alfeñique, bergante, cretino, papanatas.

http://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Capit%C3%A1n_Haddock

Comment: Añado algunos insultos del libro [Inventario general de insultos](http://www.wikiblues.net/sites/default/files/LIBRO%20DE%20LOS%20INSULTOS.PDF), si más no curiosos. Página que miro y págino que descubro alguno nuevo. 'Abrazafarolas,Ambladora, Chafalote, Chiquilicuatro, Chirimbaina, Dompereciendo, Dundo, Fazpuerca, Lameplatos, Lebraston, Macarelo, Malfario, ñiquiñaque' un sin fin pero me quedo con 'Rechiquirrititillo': *Se dice con 
desprecio y lástima de alguien a quien se considera tan minúsculo en cualquier aspecto moral o social que 
casi nos parece eso: absolutamente nada*

Comment: Si te refieres a [Luis Casamitjana Corominas] (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Casamitjana), historietista y pintor español, muchas de sus obras se datan en los años del franquismo, y la CENSURA era muy grande y las represalias podían aparecer sin saber de donde, así que más valía ser precavido y autocensurarse. Cualquier comic de esa época tenía esas 'palabrotas suaves' e incluso mucho más suaves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por supuesto que muchos textos literarios, obras teatrales, películas y hasta carteles publicitarios tenían que ser modificados debido a la censura existente en aquella época. Podemos encontrar en la red numerosa bibliografía al respecto.

Por ejemplo, [Román Gubern](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rom%C3%A1n_Gubern), en su libro *La censura: Función política y ordenamiento jurídico bajo el franquismo* (cuyo texto completo se puede encontrar [aquí](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEUQFjAC&url=http://www.omegalfa.es/downloadfile.php?file=libros/la.censura.durante.el.franquismo.pdf&ei=kg1EUrnCEMO47AbE9YG4BQ&usg=AFQjCNFb9Rvfn0G0T6Cds3fUR2mcgw3HXA&sig2=3M50gH4DRyXu-MXyF6xJGA&bvm=bv.53217764,d.ZG4&cad=rja)), nos cuenta muchísimas anécdotas relativas a la censura. En relación a los insultos y *palabrotas*, nos dice por ejemplo:

> *"En Soldado azul, de Ralph Nelson, la palabrota repetida a lo largo de
>   toda la película por la actriz Candice Bergen es **fuck!** (en inglés:
>   ¡joder!), traducida en España como **¡puñeta!**"*

En [este otro trabajo de investigación](http://www.cesfelipesegundo.com/revista/Articulos2012/HelenaLuque.pdf) sobre la censura en la obra *Salomé* de Oscar Wilde, se nos cuenta cómo los traductores utilizaban a menudo métodos para burlar a los censores. Por ejemplo, se dice:

> "*El traductor opta por traducir «**harlot**» por «**hetaira**», es decir, elige
>   una palabra más suave que la del original, pero que se refiere de
>   cualquier manera a una prostituta. Así, era probable que este insulto
>   pasara desapercibido a la censura, como así fue: por ser «hetaira» una
>   manera de referirse a las prostitutas utilizada en la antigua Grecia,
>   y por tanto, un poco rebuscada.*"

---

Con respecto a tu lista de *insultos*, se me ocurre que se podrían añadir:

[`cateto`](http://dle.rae.es/cateto), [`carcamal`](http://dle.rae.es/carcamal), [`meapilas`](http://dle.rae.es/meapilas), [`papanatas`](http://dle.rae.es/papanatas), [`zángano`](http://dle.rae.es/z%C3%A1ngano), [`zascandil`](http://dle.rae.es/zascandil), [`zopenco`](http://dle.rae.es/zopenco)...

---

Y lo siento porque probablemente no sea relevante, pero no puedo terminar este *post* sin añadir que si hay un idioma en el que existen infinidad de este tipo de *insultos* es mi lengua natal, el **gallego**, donde podemos encontrar por ejemplo:

`argalleiro`, `baldreu`, `bandallo`, `barallocas`, `camándula`, `chafalleiro`, `choromicas`, `esmorgante`, `falangueiro`, `fachendoso`, `farruco`, `farrapento`, `lacazán`, `lercha`, `lambecús`, `langrán`, `mexiricas`, `milhomes`, `moinante`, `pailán`, `paifoco`, `papamoscas`, `papaxouvas`, `pillabán`, `pimpín`, `porcallán`, `rosmón`, `trangalleiro`, `trapalleiro`, `terco`, `trouleiro`, `túzaro` y así hasta los 334 que se pueden encontrar [aquí](http://www.ciberirmandade.org/sitio2009/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1487:insulta-en-galego-334-formas-de-galeguizar-os-teus-insultos&catid=92:novas-dos-usuarios-e-usuarias&Itemid=130)..

Comment: ¡Excelente! (y como "puñeta" pasaba la censura? :)

Comment: +1 por los insultos en gallego y la fuente. Mi tío me llamaba "milhomes" de pequeño, y pensaba que era algo bueno hasta que crecí un poco :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yo, influido por ese vocabulario, pensaba que cuanto más atrás en el tiempo más se pecaba de inocente (hasta niveles cercanos a [este lugar común](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MedievalMorons)). Se me curó el prejuicio cuando leí *La Celestina* y vi la profusión de *hideputas* que gastaba Fernando de Rojas.

La respuesta a tu primera pregunta probablemente sea que tienes razón, no sé si por censura del mero insulto o porque siendo literatura juvenil había que moderarse un poco.

A tu lista yo le añadiría *necio*, *granuja* y *carcamal*. Seguro que se me ocurre alguna otra más tarde.

Answer (score 3):

En [algún lugar de internet](http://eljuegodelataba.blogspot.com/2018/01/insultos.html) (autor: Elías Moro Cuéllar) he encontrado este texto:

> En mi vida de lector, pocas veces, por no decir ninguna, me he tropezado con una sarta de insultos tan rica, tan extensa, tan con mala leche como esta del peruano Alberto Hidalgo dedicada al dos veces presidente del Perú Luis Miguel Sánchez-Cerro e incluida en este raro volumen, una edición privada que se editó en Buenos Aires en 1937.
>   No parece, no, que el de Arequipa tuviera en mucha estima al militar limeño.
>
> Ahí va esa retahíla.
>
> Esto es mucho. Basta ya de él. Hay que darle de una vez, como a los toros, el golpe de puntilla. En cuanto lo nombro, siento bajarme hasta la pluma, desde todos los extremos del alma, un tropel de adjetivos para califi­carlo mental, física y moralmente. Recitador de los dis­cursos que otros escriben, Sánchez-Cerro es el esfínter por donde se evacúa la estupidez de los secretarios. Por eso es chato, anodino, difuso, cursi, adocenado, digresi­vo, soporífero, ecoico, diluente, huero, ripioso, enriscado, banal, estólido, estulto, filatero, gárrulo, fruselero, gedeónico, blando, ezquerdeado, gelatinoso, vacío, hila­rante, burdo, bellaco, ignorante, charlatán, majadero, chirle, dengoso, zafio, diárrico, inane, cándido, latero, inconcino, minúsculo, nulo, insípido, farragoso, nescien­te, orillero, remedón, trefe, volatero, insignificante y ramplón. Es roñoso, pestilente, grosero, pusilánime, cochino, adefésico, eclámptico; fétido, escolimoso, hirsuto, fotófobo, zullón, lechuguino, currutaco, sotreta y huevón. Es arribista, pícaro, rapaz, trepador, venal, avieso, pi­llo, tunante, gregario; fanfarrón, embustero, tenebroso, hipócrita, taimado, escatológico, marrajo, cenagoso, men­daz, cínico, cocador, nocivo, atrabiliario, coccígeo, estú­pido, zorronglón, intruso, inmoral, deyectado, nepótico, zolocho, ambidextro, equívoco, zopenco, dingolondango­so, ruin, falaz, trapacero, fraudulento, lacroso, lúteo, intérlope, pravo, fecal, mazorral, lordósico, infando, im­púdico, histrión, siniestro, simulador, rastrero, pérfi­do, vitando, esquizofrénico, perillán, abyecto, mezquino, torpe, miserable, necio, ridículo, truhán, bribón, vene­noso, turbio, adulón, artero, apostático, servil, alevoso, epiléptico, perverso, funesto, protervo, cobarde y cana­lla. Todavía le hacen falta unos sustantivos: es un ba­cín, un microbio, un rufián, una bazofia, una calamidad, un cacaseno, un estropajo, un bufón, un cachivache, un sirle, un turiferario, un camaleón, una úlcera, una cloa­ca, un carnaval, un juglar, un Rigoletto, un insulto, un agravio, un cabrón, un comodín, un fariseo, una cu­caracha, un estantino, un gargajo, un piojo, un homini­caco, un monigote, un payaso, una posma, un vituperio, un ultraje, un galafate, un parásito, un sayón, un esbi­rro, un sátrapa, un fronterizo, un retardado, un esqui­zoide, un traidor, un degenerado, un baldón, un lacayo, un impostor y un perro.

Comment: Está muy bien tu hallazgo, pero hombre ¡¡hay que incluir el enlace!!

Answer (score 0):

Cada palabra hay que usarla en su contexto apropiado y, aunque normalmente se oigan por la calle expresiones más procaces, creo que todas las palabras que mencionas son parte del lenguaje corriente y se pueden usar perfectamente en casos en los que no procedan las expresiones escatológicas ni hacer mención a la familia o antepasados del aludido. Además son entendidas sin problema en la mayoría de los paises de habla hispana.

Es más, aunque desde luego no me gustaría que nadie se refiriera a mi con una de esas palabras, algunas de ellas tienen más de calificativos que de insulto: *infeliz* o *desdichado*, por ejemplo.

En cuanto a la última pregunta, mis favoritas son *Majadero* y *Pelmazo*.