# ¿Cómo llegó "berzotas" a ser un insulto?

Tags: etimología, historia, insultos

De entre la [larga lista de insultos blandos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4242/12637) que existen en español, ayer vi uno en una camiseta dedicada a *Mortadelo y Filemón*, y que era un clásico en estos tebeos:

> **[berzotas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5P5nb3C)**
>
> De *berzas*.
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. Persona ignorante o necia.

Los orígenes de algunos insultos son más fáciles de entender que los de otros, pero este me llamó la atención. Su primera inclusión en un diccionario fue en el *Domínguez suplemento* de 1853. Pero ¿cómo llegó una "berza grande" (o varias) a constituir un insulto? ¿Cuál y cuándo fue su origen?

Comment: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?berzotas

Comment: @AlexBcn interesante artículo: explica la etimología de la palabra y por qué es un insulto, pero luego divaga hacia el uso de "berza" en el idioma. Faltaría por saber cuándo y cómo se comenzó a usar "berzotas" como insulto (debió de ser antes de su inclusión en el diccionario).

Comment: Si hay algunos libros/articulos que se refieren a Joaquin Murat, representante de Napoleón en España, lamandole "El gran troncho de Berzas" como insulto, de ahi parece que viene "el berzas". En *Un día de cólera*, novela histórica de Arturo Pérez-Reverte *abucehar a Murat ya era insolencia; pero llamarlo troncho de berzas en su cara, y apedrearlo luego hasta encabritarle el caballo en medio de la rechifla general, eso no lo perdonara nunca*, relato ambientado en el 2 de mayo de 1808.

Comment: @AlexBcn pero entonces el origen no sería la verdura, sino la población de "Berzas", lo cual sería realmente interesante. ¿No te animas a investigar un poco más eso y dar una respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

En [este diccionario etimológico español en línea](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?berzotas) hay una aclaración muy buena, acerca de la etimología de la palabra berzotas:

> [...]
>
> El vocablo es un aumentativo con sufijo -ote/-ota (aumentativo y
>   despectivo), sufijo de origen provenzal y francés (-ot/-et) originado
>   al parecer en una variante latina vulgar con geminación expresiva
>   -ittus/-uttus, variante del latín -itus/-utus. Y es un aumentativo sobre la palabra berza. Berza designa a la col o a las variedades más
>   toscas de la col, pero también sobre todo a la tosca berza de pastor o
>   cenizo, verdura silvestre comestible y muy áspera, considerada de muy
>   escaso valor. Unas berzas, y más unas "berzotas" son algo tosco, bruto
>   e indigerible, aparte de algo con vida vegetativa y sin entendimiento.
>
> [...]